# How can I contribute to fixing bugs in elementary OS?

Tags: release-loki, elementary-project

I would like like to know what are the most annoying bugs in elementary os are right now and how can I contribute to elemtary os to help others get rid off these bugs.

Answer (score 2):

The page https://elementary.io/get-involved#desktop-development has two links:

- [Bitesized bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementary/+bugs?orderby=-importance&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.tag=bitesize&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_branches=on&field.has_no_branches=on&field.has_blueprints=on&field.has_no_blueprints=on&search=Search)
- [Bountied bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementary/+bugs?orderby=-importance&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.tag=bounty&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_branches=on&field.has_no_branches=on&field.has_blueprints=on&field.has_no_blueprints=on&search=Search)

Anyway you can find elementary OS bugs on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementary/+bugs